# Using jOOQ DAO to delete a record with composite key

Tags: kotlin, dao, jooq

I have a table with a composite key, and one additional field. Using standard generated jOOQ DAO, how can a I delete a record?

The API wants a `Record2`, but I'm not sure how to create one? This is what I currently do:

```
    val pojo = Pojo(key1Uuid, key2Uuid, LocalDateTime.MIN)
    dao.delete(pojo)
```

I don't like that I need to provide some bogus data to the last field.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no other way than to either:

- Use the entire POJO type (as you did)
- Supply the `Record2` type as follows

  ```
  ctx.newRecord(TABLE.COL1, TABLE.COL2).values(key1Uuid, key2Uuid)
  ```

  See: [`DSLContext.newRecord(Field<T1>, Field<T2>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-)